# How to config DAS_AGENT with wso2am-analytics-2.0.0 HA

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I'm building wso2am-analytics-2.0.0 HA according to below [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.0.1)

```
Example : (offset=1)

analytics01 192.168.2.1

analytics02 192.168.2.2
```

Q1: How to config DASServerURL in repository/conf/api-manager.xml

```
<DASServerURL>tcp://192.168.2.1:7612,tcp://192.168.2.2:7612</DASServerURL>
```

Q2 : How to conf log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.url in   repository/conf/log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.url=tcp://192.168.2.1:7612,tcp://192.168.2.2:7612
```

Is this right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use load balancing url format here. as example given in the api-manager.xml you can use the following format. You can use the same format for DAS_AGENT as well as in api-manager.xml

{tcp://localhost:7612/,tcp://localhost:7613}

For more about connection url formatting refer this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Setting+up+Multi+Receiver+and+Load+Balancing+Data+Agent).